# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto set validate causes "missing column" exception and prevent session creation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jhipster

I have a problem on columns renaming. The context of my application takes place inside Jhipster product (spring-boot + spring data jpa with hibernate 4).
Renaming ALL database columns with @Column(name="myColumnName") and inside the liquidbase xml files causes an error at test startup ONLY. If I launch application with spring-boot:run, all is working well. The problem concern running integration test only (with spring test runner) SINCE I renamed all database columns only (before, tests were running well).

Here the stack trace on loading spring context while attempting running test :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.tess2i.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tess2i.repository.UserRepository com.tess2i.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#8f062f' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#8f062f': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4659) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5281) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]

.....

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: CONEBID in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(stfcoetb) and its related supertables and secondary tables
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:583) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:258) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1598) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1521) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1422) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

To correct this startup problem. I simply remove the line :
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate inside application.yml file (the one in test package ressource).
I really don't know why this config line "interfer" with database column renaming since I use H2 in memory database. I don't like the solution. This is not the source of the problem I think. Column renaming should not depends on "hibernate tuning", mainly when using an H2 in memory database.

Any idea of the source of this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Adding @Column(name="myColumnName") will only do something if you specify create, create-drop or update for the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property. In these cases Hibernate will create the tables with columns matching your specified names or attempt to update the existing tables to match your mappings.

Answer (score 1):

The error was due to a blank space in :
@Column(name = "CONEBID ")

And that horrible mistake was not highlighted in the log message.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: conebid  in TESSICOMMUNICATION.PUBLIC.STFCOETB
```

Was expecting better output :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: 'conebid ' in TESSICOMMUNICATION.PUBLIC.STFCOETB
```

It was working at runtime because there was no validate option specified (only for test). And blank are meaningless in SQL (query, column names), so queries were working well.
But at test, it validate the mapping between JPA names and liquidbase generated hbm schema name. So XML and Java are blank sensitive and comparison is exact.

Thanks for 2 hours of searching. SIGH !